# The disappearance of וסת קבוע and הרגשות

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, niddah

At some point in history, Jewish women used to have very regularly scheduled Monthly cycles, and used to have some sensation that accompanied the onset of menstruation.  Both of these play important roles in Halacha.  The monthly cycle establishes what is called a וסת קבוע, which affects what days a woman has to take into account that her menstruation is about to begin.  The sensation (הרגשה) is a Biblical prerequisite the absence of which prevents blood from creating ritual impurity, according to most opinions.

At some point in history, women stopped having both of these.  The earliest discussion of the cessation of הרגשה that I have seen is in the שב יעקב, circa 1750.  The Aruch HaShulchan (early 20th century) asserts that women still have הרגשה, they just don't know what it is well enough to recognize it, but this is just a different way in which it was lost (it became undetected).

Rav Yaakov Kaminetzky reported that when he was in Europe most women had regular Monthly cycles.  Today, it is very rare, although apparently not unheard of, from what I have been told.

My question is - is there any Rabbinic speculation about why these changes, with significant Halachic ramifications and/or implications, occured when they did?  Are they associated with any world events?  Is there any metaphysical significance attributed to the changes?

Comment: Why do you assume that nature has changed?   Most women have pretty regular periods and lots of women have hargasha.  If you count the feeling of  blood flowing then pretty much all women have hargasha.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes ask almost anyone who gets niddah shailos and they will tell you that almost no one has an exact 30 day down to the daytime/nighttime cycle (or any perfectly consistent interval).  Many women vacillate around a certain range, but the exact precision required for halachic kevios vesset is virtually nonexistent.  "Blood flowing" is not enough - it has to specifically be the feeling of blood flowing out of the womb - see pischei teshuva to Y.D. 183.  These "facts" aren't my inventions - they are noted by halachic authorities.

Comment: @YEZ As you know the Noda' Bihuda disagreed with that Pitchei Teshuva

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan, when discussing this issue, does not contend that hargasha is a simple and obvious thing that all women feel - he acknowledges that none of them experience what a hargasha is, but they must just not be sensitive enough or not paying enough attention.

Comment: Why do you assume that the physiology of women has changed?  What evidence is there that women's menstrual cycles have changed over the past few hundred years, or even since Talmudic times?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Re-read my question.  I explained why.  Poskim talk about it.  Overtly.  Explicitly.  Directly.  They discuss what to do with the change.  I am not innovating anything here. I am repeating what they say and asking for an explanation.  Why is this so troublesome?  The Shev Yaakov explicitly says it. The Aruch HaShulchan discusses it.  R' Yaakov Kaminetzky explicitly said that it specifically changed during his Rabbinical career.  What more evidence do you want me to bring?  I can't travel through time to bring you a woman to ask her.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes If you are convinced that they all were mistaken and didn't know what they were talking about, then you can just move on to a different question.  My question is well grounded in Jewish sources.

Comment: I think the Arukh haShulchan on Nidda is from the late 19th century, not the early 20th.

Comment: Some quotes from 19th century women's health books. Thought you might find it interesting. "The average period of flow, is from three to five days, but it may be prolonged to seven or eight with out being abnormal. It continues longer as a rule in women who reside in towns than in those who live in the country. Edis' Diseases of Women, p. 112."

Comment: "The duration of the period varies in different women, and in the same woman at different times. In this country (England) its average is four or five days, while in France, Dubois and Brierre de Boismont fix eight days as the most usual length. Some women are only unwell for a few hours, while in others the period may last many days beyond the average with out being considered abnormal. Playfair's Midwifery, Vol. 1., p. 71."

Comment: I too have heard this same thing from a few rabbonim - they hardly ever hear of a real veset kavua.

Comment: Not on topic, but I wonder if there are any _halachic_ ramifications of the change in vestos. For instance, I doubt that we would act l'kulo based on it, for example to not be choshesh for a veset kavuo, not until we get another Sanhedrin. But what about l'chumra: say a woman had three repetitions to create a veset kavuo; would we say, well that is actually more likely to be a coincidence given her history and everyone's history; maybe we should continue to be choshesh for other vestos or onah beinonis anyhow?

Comment: Possibly because people moved off the land away from nature, to cities and an artificial type of living, e.g. with electric light etc.

Answer (score 1):

This was raised in Europe already - see Taharas Yisrael I think.  Note that the painful menstruation which woke women from sleep was much more common.

With higher percentages of body fat, they have more hormones perhaps.

Joking aside -

Perhaps steady low calorie diet when young puts the girl into Strong Pattern. Some women from poor countries such as Thailand kept their patterns even in USA.

This is based on small sample size.

Hormones in food - if ingested in quantity - can affect a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer to your two part question. I have heard from the Rabbis I learnt shmattas with in the name of Rav Bic & Rav Menasheh Klein who both independently attributed the erratic vestos to the suddenly widespread use of electric lines.

Comment: Im afraid i dont see how electric wires would do that

Comment: "shmattas"? Is that (in this case) Yiddish for (the checking of) _edim_?

Comment: @msh219 yes. Thats exactly what it means.

Comment: @Double AA These ideas were said in the 70s at the height of connecting cancer to electric magnetic feild from transformers and power lines. Nowadays studies are less conclusive in that respect, but the assumption is that the human body which is definitely affected by these phenomena to some degree when subjected to a given large amount, were at least affected to a lesser degree from smaller amounts.

Comment: this wouldn't really be Rabbinic speculation then, so much as Rabbis citing science.  CC @DoubleAA

Comment: @YEZ I'm not sure what your getting at.

Comment: @DoubleAA that if this is just a report of a Rabbi reporting what science says, then it doesn't answer the question as asked by the OP - "My question is - is there any **Rabbinic speculation** about ..."

Comment: @YEZ I disagree! Rabbis can speculate that science is at play here.

Comment: @DoubleAA Point conceded.  Knowing the OP personally, I happen to know he was hoping for speculation that would be more germane to Rabbis, i.e. something more based on Jewish thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17319/discussion-between-yez-and-user6591).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the electric lights that affects the cycle?

[This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1851732/) scientific paper discusses how lighting affects ovulation. Ovulation in turn usually precedes menstruation by a fixed number of days even in today's day and age.

This may explain why some women used to have their cycles linked to the day of the Jewish month; i.e. the cycle of the moon. Moonlight matters a lot more when you didn't have electric lighting.

Answer (score 0):

There is little rabbinic  speculation in an halachic context for why this changed but the standard explanation is that modern lighting and and nutrition have caused this change.

I know who had difficulties with cycles causing her to be a nidda too frequently. She was advised to use dimmer lights at night and no light at all when she slept and it worked.

I was also by a nurse who had volunteered for Doctors without Borders that in third world countries women's menstrual cycles and experiences are the same as they were in ancient times.

Comment: Artificial lighting is what I've heard as well; it keeps us off from our natural rhythms. It's said when Yemenite Jews moved from a non-electrified civilization to yes-electrified Israel, they noted this phenomenon -- from *kavua* to *not*.

Answer (score -3):

I am a Rabbi I speculate that the cycal is not set anymore

maybe becouse of feminism, since the woman stopped staying at home, or at the shtetal (some woman still have a set one) so through Menstrual synchrony (by meeting a lot of different woman that have different cycles daily) the set cycle got ruined see first comment above of @user6591

Comment: Except menstrual synchrony seemingly isn't real... http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/13683/6962

Comment: @DoubleAA It is machloikes http://www.bidmc.org/YourHealth/Therapeutic-Centers/Womens-Self-Care.aspx?ChunkID=156991

Comment: With most scientists thinking it's unsupported by evidence...

Comment: @DoubleAA a goyeshe machloikes b'metsius we go boser rov : ) (the question allowed me to speculate)